# XDK built app not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find an answer. I use Intel XDK for Cordova/Phonegap development.

Everything is ok (emulate tabs, debug, etc.). I went to Build tab and get my .apk, moved it to SD card and installed, but, it doesn't work when run.

If I build my source with Phonegap Build (Online), everything works fine.

My JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){ return; }, true);
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() 
    {
        //navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        var server = 'http://xxxxxx/index.php?';
        var user_uuid = device.uuid;
        $( document ).ready
        (
            function()
            {
                $("#main_content").css("top", "50%");
                $("#main_content").css("margin-top", "-"+($("#main_content").height()/2)+"px");
                $("#main_content").show();
                $("#big_img_load").attr("src", "img/ajax-loader.gif");
                var xinv = setInterval
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
                        if(networkState.trim() == 'none')
                            $("#no_internet").show(); 
                        else 
                        {
                            $.post
                            (
                                server+"do=boot",{useruuid: user_uuid},function(data)
                                {
                                    if(data.trim() != "ok")
                                        window.location = "error.html";
                                    else
                                    {
                                        clearInterval(xinv);
                                        window.location = "app.html";
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    1000
                );
            }
        );
    };

</script>
```

It remains in loading: No internet check, no POST to the URL, nothing.

Where is the problem? Why only build from XDK is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is you do not have the domain whitelisting section in the build settings set correctly for your app. See this article for some hints: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cordova-cli-412-domain-whitelisting-with-intel-xdk-for-ajax-and-launching-external-apps and make sure to build your app using Crosswalk, not Android, for best results on Android devices.

Comment: works fine! I changed at Android not at Android Crosswalk. Thanks!